# Accessing an osgi declarative service in a java project

Tags: java, osgi

Im trying to access an osgi ds in a java project. I found an example like this on the internet:

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference serviceReference = context.getServiceReference(MyClass.class.getName());
MyClass blah = (MyClass) new ServiceTracker(context, serviceReference, null).getService();
blah.doStuff();
```

The problem here is that if i run this in a java class the "context" variable is null. I guess thats probably because its not in an osgi bundle.

I tried chaning things and it works if i change it like this:

```
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Myclass.class).getBundleContext();
```

But to be honest i really dont understand this bundle context. **What exactly is it and can it be the same class that the reference class is?**

Manual states the following:
context - The BundleContext against which the tracking is done.
... but that doesent make things clearer for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Class)` only returns non-null if the class you pass in was loaded by an OSGi bundle classloader. That means you actually need to be in an OSGi bundle.

You need to be much clearer about what you're trying to do. "Accessing an OSGi DS in a Java project" is pretty much meaningless. Also since it seems you're just starting out with OSGi, why not start with something simple like working through a basic tutorial, rather than jumping in at the deep end?

Finally notice that the following code snippet is nonsense: `MyClass.class.getClass()`. The literal `MyClass.class` already gives you the class you want... if you then call `getClass` on it you get the Class of `java.lang.Class`! This is almost certainly not what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. MyClass.class is correct, just made a mistake while copying. I'll correct my question.
But the real point of the question was to understand what the context variable is? Can it be the context of the same class that im getting the reference of?

Comment: BundleContext is a handle for accessing the OSGi API. The OSGi framework gives each bundle its own context object which that bundle is supposed to use any time it calls OSGi. That way, OSGi always knows which bundle is calling it.

Comment: So is it ok if the handle is the same as reference?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. BundleContext and ServiceReference are different types, so they're obviously not the same.